Configured an Entity to have the id as UUID, Why after doing a findAll it returns different Ids values that diff of stored in the database?
Basically the idea begins creating a check for the table, but MySql rejects the creation of the check because the id has the auto_increment. Then the idea is to establish the check using UUID, and let JPA (Hibernate) to auto generate the ids.
The table has two rows:
550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000    ACCOUNT_CREATED_SUCCESFULLY
550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440001    UNKNOWN_TEMPLATE

That I initially sets the id manually, because when I deploy the application I have a @PostConstruct that loads the information from the table, and that was throwing an exception due to the ids that originally has the auto_increment values (1, 2).
Doing this change, the application deploys fine, but doing a .findAll() through the controller ("/emails/list") it returns the following result:
[{"id": "35353065-3834-3030-2d65-3239622d3431","key": "ACCOUNT_CREATED_SUCCESFULLY", ...},
  {"id": "35353065-3834-3030-2d65-3239622d3431","key": "ACCOUNT_CREATED_SUCCESFULLY", ... }]

As you can see the id is different and repeats the first row two times. Somebody knows what is the reason of this behavior?
In the code I have this for the id column:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)                            
@Column(name = "id", length=36, updatable = false , nullable = false)                
private UUID id;

If I do the select in the database I get the right rows as I showed above.
550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000
550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440001

Another thing, that may helps to discover what is happening is that the table has another id that references the table itself through the id, here is a general view of the entity definition:
@Entity
@Table(name = "email_template")
public class AppEmailTemplate { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)                            
    @Column(name = "id", length = 36, updatable = false, nullable = false)                
    private UUID id;

...

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_template_mirror", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "reference_itself_template"))
    private AppEmailTemplate templateHelper;

    // Other fields, getters, setters
} 

The project uses Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.3.2
I want to get the information exactly as is it in the database table. Because actually is returning an invalid result.

I updated the ids running:
update email_template set id = UUID()

After that I get the following ids
844cf1be-6424-11ef-9d10-5cea1d8080bf    ACCOUNT_CREATED_SUCCESFULLY
844cfcf5-6424-11ef-9d10-5cea1d8080bf    UNKNOWN_TEMPLATE

Now the request .findAll() works fine.
Asking to IA, that unexpected behavior may be caused due to the format of the ids, considering Manually Generated UUIDs, collision or incorrect mapping, UUID version differences and more.
